# How to remove a child block from YML in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to compare two `yml` files and removing a block based on some conditions using shell script. I'm using this `YML` parser, https://gist.github.com/pkuczynski/8665367 for the comparison of `yml` files. But I'm really strugglig a lot for removing the block from them. For example,

```
tool:
  image: tool.xxx.com/platform/app:dev
  log_driver: syslog
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "54325:80"
    - "543325:80"
  volume:
    - "a:b"

tool1:
  image: tool1.xxx.com/platform/app:dev
  log_driver: syslog
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "54325:80"
    - "543325:80"
  volume:
    - "a:b"
```

How to remove ports block under `tool` and which will make output similar to,

```
tool:
  image: tool.xxx.com/platform/app:dev
  log_driver: syslog
  restart: always
  volume:
    - "a:b"

tool1:
  image: tool1.xxx.com/platform/app:dev
  log_driver: syslog
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "54325:80"
    - "543325:80"
  volume:
    - "a:b"
```

I tried somethings using awk and sed, but I don't know exactly as it contains some complex condition involving multiple lines.

Any help or suggestion on this would be greatly helpful and much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk '$1 == "tool:"{t=1}
   t==1 && $1 == "ports:"{t++; next}
   t==2 && /:[[:blank:]]*$/{t=0}
   t != 2' file.yml
```

**Explanation:**

- Set `t=1` when we encounter `tool:` as first column
- When `t==1`, make `t=2` when we encounter 1st column in `ports:`
- Reset to `t=0` when `t==2` and we get a line that ends with `:`
- print each line when `t != 2` (means we are not in `tool: -> ports:` section)

**Output:**

```
tool:
  image: tool.xxx.com/platform/app:dev
  log_driver: syslog
  restart: always
  volume:
    - "a:b"

tool1:
  image: tool1.xxx.com/platform/app:dev
  log_driver: syslog
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "54325:80"
    - "543325:80"
  volume:
    - "a:b"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It would be great if you give a small explanation of this works. Also it is removing everything that comes after ports like sub blocks (like volume) or main blocks (like tool1) or whatever comes after that..

Comment: It is removing only sub block that starts with `ports:` that comes under main `tool:` block. See edited answer for explanation.

Comment: Not sure why, but I'm getting this as output http://imgur.com/iLDeQsZ in my Ubuntu shell (tried in multiple system with both `zsh` and `bash`) with same code present here, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMSFViVjNNRDZxWms . Any clue?

Comment: I understand it is working (even in the tutorialspoint link I posted in my previous comment). I'm just wondering why it is not working in Ubuntu shell (tried both in sh and zsh in 2 systems).

Comment: Hmm not sure because it doesn't even require gnu awk. I have tested it on OSX and Ubuntu and it works on both systems.

Comment: Have you tested it with the same code present here in this link, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMNE5PdDRkS0FxdHc

Comment: Yes I copied data from [your link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMNE5PdDRkS0FxdHc) and it is still working fine. You need to run it as `awk '$1 == "tool:"{t=1}
   t==1 && $1 == "ports:"{t++; next}
   t==2 && /:[[:blank:]]*$/{t=0}
   t != 2' docker-compose.yml`