# Ubuntu bash awk odd behaviour

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, awk

I'm trying to remove a block from yml file using the following command,

```
awk '$1 == "tool:"{t=1}
   t==1 && $1 == "ports:"{t++; next}
   t==2 && /:[[:blank:]]*$/{t=0}
   t != 2' file.yml
```

for the following yml,

```
tool:
  image: tool.xxx.com/platform/app:dev
  log_driver: syslog
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "54325:80"
    - "543325:80"
  volume:
    - "a:b"

tool1:
  image: tool1.xxx.com/platform/app:dev
  log_driver: syslog
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "54325:80"
    - "543325:80"
  volume:
    - "a:b"
```

The goal is to remove the `ports` sub-block from the `tool` main block.
This answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37256824/698072 seems to be perfectly valid when tried [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMNE5PdDRkS0FxdHc). But it is removing everything right from the ports until the end of yml file in my Ubuntu 14.04 (tried both in sh and zsh in multiple systems of 14.04).

Expected:

```
tool:                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  image: tool.xxx.com/platform/app:dev                                                                                                                                                                                    
  log_driver: syslog                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  restart: always                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  volume:                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    - "a:b"                                                                                                                                                                                                               

tool1:                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  image: tool1.xxx.com/platform/app:dev                                                                                                                                                                                   
  log_driver: syslog                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  restart: always                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  ports:                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    - "54325:80"                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    - "543325:80"                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  volume:                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    - "a:b"
```

Output:

```
tool:
  image: tool.xxx.com/platform/app:dev
  log_driver: syslog
  restart: always
```

Any help on this peculiar case would be really great.

Comment: Please don't include images of console sessions. Copy and paste the *text* into your question.

Comment: What version of awk are you using? Not all support character classes (`[[:blank:]]`) so try `[ \t]` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made few changes in my earlier `awk` command to take care of possibility that your `yml` has DOS line endings.

```
awk '{sub(/\r$/, "")}
     $1 == "tool:"{t=1}
     t==1 && $1 == "ports:"{t++; next}
     t==2 && /:\s*$/{t=0}
     t != 2' file.yml
```

Looks like Ubuntu `awk` doesn't support POSIX classes `[[:blank:]]` or `[[:space:]]` so we'll need to use `\s` to match white-spaces.

Comment: This worked exactly, `echo "$(cat docker-compose.yml)" | awk '$1 == "tool:"{t=1} t==1 && $1 == "ports:"{t++; next} t==2 && /s*$/{t=0} t != 2'`. Thanks for your valuable time and sorry for the confusion..

Comment: Which version of awk do you have on your Ubuntu? gawk definitely supports the posix classes.

Comment: Yes gnu awk or even BSD awk definitely support POSIX classes. It seems my Ubuntu shipped with `mawk 1.3.3`.

Comment: That's amazing that it supports the shorthand `\s` but not the longhand `[:space:]`!

Answer (score 0):

If the file was created on windows and therefore has windows line endings (CR-LF), then the pattern `/:[[:blank:]]*$/` will fail

`[[:blank:]]` only matches tabs and spaces. To match any whitespace character, including `\r` (carriage return), use `[[:space:]]`.

If that turns out to be the problem, consider using `dos2unix` or similar to remove the incorrect line endings, as they will cause you other problems with other utilities.