# How to delete a main block from YML

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a YML file with content similar to,

```
test:
  volumes:
    - /u01/test-service/conf:/root/config

testmanager:
  port:
    - "2222:80"
```

I want to delete test or testmanager block based on some conditions. Here is the awk expression I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256414/how-to-remove-a-child-block-from-yml-in-shell-script),

```
awk '{sub(/\r$/, "")}
                     $1 == "test:"{t=1}
                     t==1 && $1 != "test:" {t++; next}
                     t==2 && /:\s*$/{t=0}
                     t != 2'
```

This deletes everything under test but keeps the string "test:". Something like this,

```
reportservice:
reportmanager:
  port:
    - "2222:80"
```

How to fix this? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the shown input you can use this awk command with empty `RS`:

```
awk -v RS= '!/^[[:blank:]]*test:/' file.yml

testmanager:
  port:
    - "2222:80"
```

This assumes there is an empty line between each block. If this doesn't work you can modify your existing command you can do:

```
awk '{sub(/\r$/, "")}
     $1 == "test:"{t=1}
     t==1 && $1 != "test:" {t++; next}
     t==2 && /:\s*$/{t=0}
    !t' file.yml
```