# How to remove a specific key from yaml file in bash

Tags: bash, key, yaml

I'm trying to remove 1 key from YAML file that for example looks like this:

```
users:
  - aaa
  - bbb

roles:
  - aaa
  - bbb
  - ccc
```

I'm looking for a way to remove only this `users.aaa` without touching `roles.aaa`, so that the output would be:

```
users:
  - bbb

roles:
  - aaa
  - bbb
  - ccc
```

Any ideas? Would be nice if it could be done by some standard tools, without installing any additional commands.

I've been trying to use this example:
[How to remove a child block from YML in shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256414/how-to-remove-a-child-block-from-yml-in-shell-script)
but it didn't work. I'm not an awk master.

Comment: First of all, within your example, you are not removing a key, you are removing a sequence item. Second: since that YAML file e.g. could look like the one liner `{users: ["aaa", 'bbb'], roles: [aaa, 'bbb', "ccc"]}`, with exactly the same semantics, you should refrain from using bash and apply a proper YAML loader/dumper to do these kind of things. Your example can be done as a one-liner using Python, and that would handle your syntax **and** the equivalent I indicate in this comment without a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you can rely on the input to be formatted as you describe (noting well that there are alternative YAML syntaxes for both mappings and sequences) then you can do this with `sed`:

```
sed -i -e '/^users:/,/^[^ ]*:/!n;/[ ]\{1,\}-[ ]\{1,\}aaa/d' my_file.yaml
```

That sed expression is a tad complicated, so let's break it down.  There are two commands, separated by a semicolon (`;`):

- `/^users:/,/^[^ ]*:/!n`

  That's a negated (`!`) address range for a next line (`n`) command.  It causes all lines not matched by the address range to be passed through unchanged to the output.  The only lines subject to further processing are those in the range (or ranges) of lines starting with one matching the regex `/^users:/` and continuing through the next subsequent line matching the regex `/^[^ ]*:/`.  In other words, the `users` key itself, the elements of the value associated with that key, plus (harmlessly) the next key itself.
- `/[ ]\{1,\}-[ ]\{1,\}aaa/d`

  Those lines that pass through the filter of the first command are subject to this one, which matches the sequence element you're looking for by the provided regex and removes it (`d`) from the output.  This is the last command, so lines that are not deleted here are passed through to the output.

Answer (score 1):

Nice challnge for awk script. I would try the following script:

```
awk '/^[[:alpha:]]+:/ {level1=$0; next} level1 ~ "users" && /aaa/ {next} 1' input.yml
```